# Is there a way to scan for BLE devices that does not use callbacks?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an application in Android that scans for **Bluetooth Low Energy** devices nearby using only Android's API. There are any functions that scans and return a list of all the detected devices? Currently I'm using callbacks but I need to call this function more times per second so callback is not the way.

Comment: what do you mean by callback?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think that it is possible without using Callback functions as much as I know.

Callbacks are important part of the scanning process.

This is the code for Creating the callback

```
private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
          //code for what you want to do when a device is found
        }
    };
```

ScanResult is the data structure which holds the information about the device and the service data which it has if any.

This is to start scanning

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
```

This is to stop scanning

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why would you wrap those in an AsyncTask?

Comment: We need to wrap it in AsyncTask because they are continuous operations which if ran on the UI Thread would lead to no other action involving UI (for eg - Button Press/Text Input) to be possible to run at the same time. So it's preferable to run it on a separate thread.

Comment: No, both start and stop scan are asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Emil  is the scanCallback also an asynchronous operation?
Meaning, while one callback is executing, is it possible for another be called by the OS?
Or might it be advantageous to receive then run the callback asynchronously?

Comment: Of course what I was referring to exactly were the onScanResult/onScanFailed functions of the scanCallback, are these called asynchronously or not by the OS?

Comment: They are put on a message queue executed by a `Handler`, usually running on the main thread, so they will be executed in order and only one callback in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

No, Bluetooth LE scanning is naturally an asynchronous process that requires callbacks. Also, calling to scan more times per second, won't improve your chances of getting more results. The Bluetooth LE scanning process runs continuously and returns all possible results.